# CLASSPATH set but java compiler cannot find class files

Tags: java, classpath

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 and have installed jdk-6u30-linux-i586.bin
and have a directory /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_30 and everything was working
and compiling fine even without a CLASSPATH so long as I had
export PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_30/bin:$PATH in my ~/.bashrc
and executed java from a fresh new shell (not sure why no
CLASSPATH is needed in my env).

Now I am trying to use the following class libraries:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/downloads/list
google-api-java-client-1.6.0-beta.zip

I downloaded and extracted the zip file to a /usr/local/google directory
which now contains all the jar files. I then try to compile the BigQuerySample
from http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/ClientLogin

$ javac -cp /usr/local/google BigQuerySample.java

and I get:

BigQuerySample.java:1: package com.google.api.client.googleapis does not exist
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.*;

and so on for all the imported packages except for java.io.*;

I know this should be a simple classpath problem but adjusting the classpath
on the command line or in the environment with export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/google
does not get rid of the errors. I have tried jar -tvf *jar for each jar file and the
stuff is there, so why is the java compiler not finding the includes?

Thanks,

John Goche

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
javac -Djava.ext.dirs=/usr/local/google BigQuerySample.java
```

Comment: Hi, that worked as far as the complaints from the includes goes but there are still symbols which the java compiler cannot find such as GoogleTransport, JSONCParser, etc...

Comment: I am not sure if you have downloaded all libraries required. You may check if all libraries are under this directory including GoogleTransport etc. And if you want to run this app, you also need to set the option: java -Djava.ext.dirs=...

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the **jar** to your classpath like this:

```
javac -cp "$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/google/google-api-client-1.6.0-beta.jar" BigQuerySample.java
```

Or use a [wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) to add all jars:

```
javac -cp "$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/google/*:/usr/local/google/dependencies/*" BigQuerySample.java
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately some of the classes from the example are not defined in the jar files which means the example is no good. I have checked it with: for i in *jar; do /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_30/bin/jar -tvf $i >> out; done             but no trace of the GoogleTransport class.

Comment: The `ClientLogin` API is legacy. I believe you need to use `OAuth` now. See if you can find an updated example.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to explicitly specify all the references JARs.

```
javac -cp /usr/local/google/file1.jar:/usr/local/google/file2.jar:. BigQuerySample.java
```

Same thing while running...

```
java -cp /usr/local/google/file1.jar:/usr/local/google/file2.jar:. BigQuerySample
```

Answer (score 1):

When including jars in the classpath either specifically indicate the jars to include or use wildcards to include all jars in a directory. So for your example you could use:

```
javac -cp /usr/local/google/google-api.jar BigQuerySample.java
```

or

```
javac -cp /usr/local/google/* BigQuerySample.java
```

For more help using including jars in the classpath see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath).